# ROS Answers SE migration: move it issues

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after moving from ros indigo to ros kinetic, i'm trying to modify my code to work on ros kinetic, i am having some issues with moveit.

[image: image description]
https://i.imgur.com/4kCEfzI.png

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279138/move-it-issues/) by [omer91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33188/omer91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-08**:
Please copy-paste text directly. *Do not* post screenshots of text, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i found out the problem was i had to declare that im using c++11.
had to add to the cmake:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

---

Originally posted by [omer91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33188/omer91/) with karma: 60 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that first error is an issue with your code, not MoveIt!:

```
error: 'robot_model_' was not declared in this scope
```

So check carefully whether robot_model_ was declared in the right spot.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2